# How to proceed some logic when item selected from dropdownlist and before the selected item inserted to ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this dropdownlist directive.

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-model="editor.frequency"
        ng-options="item as item.Name for item in editor.frequencies"
        ng-change="editor.checkSiteFrequencyInspections(editor.frequency, {{editor.frequency}});">
</select>
```

When user click on some option in dropdownlist the selected item is inserted to property named `frequency`.

I need to proceed some logic after user select item from dropdownlist and before it inserted to property named `frequency`(only after the logic is proceed the `frequency` get the selected item).

Any idea how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

To execute a function before the model changes, use a directive to add a `$parser` to the `ngModelController`:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive("preChange", function () {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs,ngModelCtrl) {
             console.log("Pre instantiated")
             ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                  scope.$eval(attrs.preChange, {$value: value});
                  return value;
             })
        }
    }
});
```

The above directive adds a `$parser` to the `ngModelController` which executes an AngularJS Expression defined by the `pre-change` attribute. The new value is exposed as `$value`.

Usage:

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-model="editor.frequency"
        ng-options="item as item.name for item in editor.frequencies"
        ng-change="change(editor.frequency.name)"
        pre-change="pre($value.name)">
</select>
```

From the Docs:

> ### `$parsers`
>
> Array of functions to execute, as a pipeline, whenever the control reads value from the DOM. The functions are called in array order, each passing its return value through to the next. The last return value is forwarded to the $validators collection.

-- [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference -- `$parsers`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers)

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nz8v19ua/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess `ng-change` or `$watch` (which are usually used to detect changes) won't be helpful to you because they are called/executed after the change have occurred.

What about this simple hack?

1. In your `html` instead of using `editor.frequency` in `ng-model`,
   you can use a temporary `$scope` variable (viz.,
   `$scope.editor.temp`)

   ```
   <select class="form-control"
       ng-model="editor.temp"
       ng-options="item as item.Name for item in editor.frequencies">
   </select>
   ```
2. and in your `controller`, you watch for changes in
   `$scope.editor.temp` and as soon as you detect any change, you
   perform your pre-frequency-assigned logic here and afterwards, you
   can assign the value to actual `$scope.editor.frequency`

   ```
   $scope.$watch('editor.temp', function(newValue, oldValue) {
       //perform your pre-frequency-is-assigned logic here
       $scope.editor.frequency = newValue;
   });
   ```